# Shift column data vertically upward in mysql

Tags: mysql, spring-boot

```
|ID| countries | products        |
|--| --------  | --------------- |
|1 | China     | prod 1          |
|2 | India     | prod 2          |
|3 | USA       | prod 3          |
|4 | Russia    | prod 4          |
-------------------------------
```

Resulting

| ID | countries | products |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | China | prod 1 |
| 2 | India | prod 3 |
| 3 | USA | prod 4 |
| 4 | Russia |  |

Is it possible to have a MySQL query to remove data from a column and move the data in that column upwards? EG: in the table, I want to remove prod2.

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  "Upward" requires some nothing of ordering.  How is that determined?

Comment: Yes, the data is ordered using sequential IDs. Sorry, I forgot to mention. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are talking about how to query data in that form, something like that may work for the concrete example:

```
select countries,
       case when products = 'prod2' then null else products end as products
from my_table
order by 2 asc;
```

Point is to specify the "leave empty" cases in a `case` clause and then use `order by` to push the ones left empty to end.

This will not change data in the original table though. In the original table there is no such thing as order in SQL. Only query results are ordered.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions:

```
select t.*,
       (case when id >= prod2_id then next_country else country
        end) as new_country
from (select t.*,
             lead(country) over (order by id) as next_country
             max(case when product = 'prod2' then id end) over () as prod2_id
      from t
     ) t
```

Answer (score 0):

Update the table with a self join:

```
UPDATE tablename t1
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE products = 'prod 2') t2
ON t2.ID <= t1.ID
LEFT JOIN tablename t3 ON t3.ID = t1.ID + 1
SET t1.products = t3.products;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=01ed73735e0705192b461b87282c16b7).